# Cargar datos de SQLite en listview

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-listview

Quisiera saber como cargar los datos de una consulta sql en un list view. Por mas que lo intento no consigo hacerlo :S

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table usuarios(nombre text primary key, edad int, puntuacion int)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table usuarios");
    db.execSQL("create table usuarios(nombre text primary key, edad int, puntuacion int)");

}

public class Ranking extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ListView lv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ranking);

        lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);

        ArrayList <String> ranking = new ArrayList<>();

        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper juego = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "juego", null, 5);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = juego.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor fila = bd.rawQuery("select nombre, puntuacion from usuarios", null);
        if(fila.moveToFirst()){
            fila = bd.rawQuery("select nombre, puntuacion from usuarios", null);
            ranking.add(fila.getString(0) + " - " + fila.getString(1));
            while(fila.moveToNext()){
                ranking.add(fila.getString(0) + " - " + fila.getString(1));
            }
        }
        bd.close();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ranking);
        lv1.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

[image: captura1]

Comment: Hay algún error al ejecutar tu código? La aplicación se detiene? Podrías dar mas detalles de que es lo que pasa

Comment: Simplemente salta el error de que la aplicacion se ha detenido, no da mas detalles.

Comment: Puedes ver el error en el log de android studio, puedes verificar cual es?

Comment: Estoy viendo el log pero es como si leyera chino porque no entiendo nada. Soy muy nuevo en esto de android y estoy un poco perdido jeje

Comment: Podrías agregar una captura del inicio del log, así podremos identificar el error mas fácil

Comment: Actualizo la pregunta con la foto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
public class Ranking extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ListView lv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ranking);

        lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv1);

        ArrayList <String> ranking = new ArrayList<>();

        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper juego = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "juego", null, 5);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = juego.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor fila = bd.rawQuery("select nombre, puntuacion from usuarios", null);
        if(fila.moveToFirst()){
            do{
              ranking.add(fila.getString(0) + " - " + fila.getString(1))); 
            }while(fila.moveToNext())
        }
        bd.close();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ranking);
        lv1.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Comment: Me da un pequeño error aqui:  fila.Integer(1)). Dice que Cannot resolve method Integer(int)

Comment: Creo que lo he arreglado y ya por fin sale. He cambiado el Integer(1) por .getString(1). En el emulador ahora sale el nombre seguido de - y null, pero como el valor de puntuacion esta vacio en todos ellos supongo que es normal. Que opinais?

Comment: Oh, si pues creo que tu duda quedo resuelta, utilice el método getInt(), porque pensé que la puntuación la guardabas a modo de numero, corrijo la respuesta para que la marques como correcta

Comment: Si, si en la base de datos puntuación esta como int. Pero si pongo Integer(1) me da fallo, por eso lo cambié a getString.

Comment: Sería buena idea que agregaras una explicación en tu respuesta de lo que realiza este códio @AarónZúñiga revisar [answer].